# How do I count how many times a specific value shows up in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm searching for "***" in the A column, I need to know how many times it appears so that I can loop my code that many times. I can't seem to find out how to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you actually searching for how many cells contain three asterisks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your cells just have `"***"` in them and it's not anything else, you can invoke the worksheet function CountIF

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), "~*"&"~*"&"~*")
```

Edited per TMH8885's comment and the asterisk being a wildcard. The tilde does seem to work.

Comment: This will not work, as the asterisk is a wildcard character.  This would actually return the number of rows containing text.

Comment: If you'd like to make the proper change, you have to use the tilda character (~) to tell excel you mean the literal asterisk: "~*"   If you concatenate 3 of them in a row, it will achieve the desired result.

Comment: Close but a slight change was needed after your edit. I edited the code to concatenate the three literal asterisks in a row.  As you had it, it would have found any cells that started with an asterisk.  You have to tell Excel each literal asterisk.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Though "~*~*~*"  would also work.

Comment: You are correct, the &'s just help to show that each one is an individual asterisk. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this function within excel: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214153

It shows the function: `=COUNTIF(range,"text")` which you can use as `=COUNTIF(A:A,"***")`

**UPDATE** Actually need to escape wildcards so it would be: `=COUNTIF(A:A,"~*~*~*")`

It counts the number of matched to your pattern "***" in column A.

Comment: Please post a summary of the article, at the very least outlining the function and its basic use.